¿Alguien puede explicar detalladamente cómo funciona el siguiente algoritmo python?
Tu tarea es escribir un programa que lea la cantidad de bloques que tienen los constructores, y generar la altura de la pirámide que se puede construir utilizando estos bloques. La altura se mide por el número de capas completas - si los constructores no tienen la cantidad suficiente de bloques y no pueden completar la siguiente capa, terminan su trabajo inmediatamente.
bloques = int(input("Introduzca el número de bloques disponibles: "))
 
altura = 0

filas = 1 

while filas <= bloques:

    altura = altura + 1

    bloques = bloques - filas

    filas = filas + 1 
 
print("La altura de la pirámide es de: ", altura)


Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué específicamente no entiendes del código propuesto. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Lo que hace el código es calcular la altura de la pirámide que puedes formar con el la cantidad de bloques que ingreses en el input
/// aqui se incializan las variables
bloques = int(input("Introduzca el número de bloques disponibles: "))
 
altura = 0

filas = 1 

/// la condición del bucle evalua que la cantidad de bloques sean suficientes para crear una fila
while filas <= bloques:

    /// si se cumple la condición anterior significa que puede crear una fila, por lo tanto aumenta la altura en 1    
    altura = altura + 1

    /// aquí resta la cantidad de bloques que se utilizaron para crear la fila
    bloques = bloques - filas

    /// aquí lo que hace es que aumenta en 1 la cantidad necesaria para crear una fila
    filas = filas + 1 

/// si los bloques restantes no alcanzan para formar una nueva fila se termina el bucle y se muestra la altura que la pirámide alcanzó
print("La altura de la pirámide es de: ", altura)


Ayúdanos a mantener la calidad en el sitio, respondiendo preguntas realizadas con base en [ask], saludos.
